# Decreasing loading time of HTML5 Video

Tags: html, html5-video

Live site- http://www.thecompletefinancialplan.com

I use `videojs` player to add video on my site.

Video: KeithKolinskyCFP.mp4 - 25.5MB,
       KeithKolinskyCFP.webm - 31MB,
       KeithKolinskyCFP.ogv - 50MB

I've waited at least 30 seconds and it still has not begun to play in mozilla, my internet connect is not slow. Any idea how can i decrease loading time of that Video.

My code-

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" poster="http://www.thecompletefinancialplan.com/images/video.jpg" width="320" height="240" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://www.thecompletefinancialplan.com/Keith_video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://www.thecompletefinancialplan.com/Keith_video.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://www.thecompletefinancialplan.com/Keith_video.ogv" type='video/ogg' />

   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="320" height="240">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thecompletefinancialplan.com%2FKeith_video.jpg',{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thecompletefinancialplan.com%2FKeith_video.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
    <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="http://www.thecompletefinancialplan.com/images/video.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
</object>

</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve tried it few seconds ago with Chrome 32 for Mac and it loaded immediately.
When I try to load it with Firefox it doesn´t load.

I got some very long loading times with Firefox. So maybe there is an failure with the "videojs" Player-framework.

Try it on a test site with the normal html5 video tags or with another video-player framework.

I tested it myself here: http://lucas-recknagel.de/video.html in chrome no problem but in Firefox the standard player show an error with the video type / MIME type.

So you probably try to re-export your webm file.

Hope that helps.